# What is the "Equip items in bag?" pop-up for?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

When I enter a dungeon, the game asks me if I want to equip items in the bag. I've answered both "yes" and "no", but I can't see any difference in the fights or characters no matter which response I pick.

What does that pop-up mean? Do I need to actually have *equipment* with me for that choice to make any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you first prepare to go into a dungeon, you may elect to bring items with you. These will take up your 20+ slots, of course. General items to bring would be food (in case you want healing), and equipment that is better than what the adventurer currently has equipped. The prompt you get at the beginning, if you select yes, **auto-equips all pieces of equipment that are better than the adventurer's current equipment**. Things like rings will have to be manually equipped though, even if the adventurer has an empty slot.

Adventurers will buy equipment from you, and if it's better they will equip it. But sometimes they buy other stuff, or start selling you things, so you've got a nice shiny equipment that'd look great on them just sitting in your inventory. By bringing it into the dungeon, they can use it.

Keep in mind, though, that such items are thus part of your items carried. If your adventurer falls, you can only take 1-3 items back with you, and such equipment counts. As such, either only bring one piece of good equipment, or have plenty of spares. At the end of the dungeon run, you'll get it back into your inventory as normal for any other item in your bag.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  If you put some items that your chosen adventurer can use in your inventory ahead of time, this option will allow you to let the hero "borrow" that equipment and use it during your dungeon run.  Assuming you get out of the dungeon successfully, you get all the equipment back.  But if you die, it is treated the same as your other inventory items and you have to select it as one of your items to keep in order to avoid losing it.